# Newbie in front of a LinkedList code C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have this code in front but I can't build a linked list with more than one element. I see that in the methode "einsetzenNach" the code block in the if statement will never executed. The reason is that the cursor will never get != 0
The code original was in Java.
I am thankful for any tips.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EinfachVerketteteListe
{


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Liste myList = new Liste();

        myList.einsetzenVor(1, "Nr01");
        myList.einsetzenVor(2, "Nr02");
        myList.einsetzenNach(2, "Nr02");
        myList.einsetzenNach(3, "Nr03");
        myList.inhalt(3);
        myList.laenge();
        myList.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the Cell class

```
class Zelle
{
   // Contents
   public Object inhalt;
   // Next cell
   public Zelle next;

   public Zelle(Object el) 
   {
        inhalt = el;
   }
   public Zelle(Object el, Zelle z)
   {
        inhalt = el;
        next = z;
   }
   public Zelle(Zelle z)
   {
       next = z;
   }
}
```

Our custom list class

```
public class Liste
{
    // Start element
    private Zelle anfang;
    // Current Element
    private Zelle cursor;

    /// <summary>

    /// There are no more items in the list, start is null
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>start == null</returns>
    public Boolean IstLeer()
    {
        return anfang == null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Length of the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>l = listlenght</returns>
    public int laenge()
    {
        Zelle cur = anfang;
        int l = 0;
        while (cur != null)
        {
            l++;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return l;
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check of the declared position is valid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Position</param>
    /// <returns>true/false</returns>
    public Boolean istGueltigePosition(int p) 
     {
      return (p >= 1) && (p <= laenge() );
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Set cursor on a specific position</param>
    public void setzeCursor(int p) 
    {
        cursor = null;
        if (istGueltigePosition(p))
        {
            Zelle cur = anfang; 

            // cur.next is null. The reason is that there is only one element in the list
            // How can I fix this block. However I assume the code will work. 
            // Maybe I handle something not in the correct order.

            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) 
            { cur = cur.next; }
            cursor = cur;
        }
    }
```

Maybe the Methode initCursor() is the answer to my understanding problem.
However I have no idea in which way I can use this methode to print out the first element.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initial Position Cursor 
    /// </summary>
     public void initCursor()
     {
         cursor = anfang;
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Search for specific object and return it's index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Zu findende Daten</param>
    /// <returns>p = Index</returns>
    public int suche(Object e)
    {
        cursor = null;
        int p = 0, l = 0;
        Zelle z = anfang;

        while (z != null)
        {
            l++;
            if ( z.inhalt == e )
            {
                p = l;
                cursor = z;
                break;
            }
            z = z.next;
        }
        return p;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert cell after element p
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Position</param>
    /// <param name="e">Daten</param>
    public void einsetzenNach(int p, Object e)
    {
        setzeCursor(p);
```

This if statment will never get !=0

```
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            Zelle z = new Zelle(e, cursor.next);
            cursor.next = z;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert cell after element p
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">Position</param>
    /// <param name="e">Daten</param>

    public void einsetzenVor(int p, Object e)
    {
        if (p > 1) einsetzenNach(p-1,e);
        else
        {
            // Insert at the beginning
            Zelle z = new Zelle(e, anfang);
            anfang = z;
        }
    }

    public void loesche(int p)
    {
        if (istGueltigePosition(p))
        {
            if (p == 1) // Lösche 1. Object
                anfang = anfang.next;
            else
            {
                setzeCursor(p - 1);
                cursor.next = cursor.next.next;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the content
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p">position</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Object inhalt(int p)
    {
        setzeCursor(p);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        return cursor.inhalt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// next cell/data
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Daten</returns>
    public Object naechstes()
    {
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        Object e = cursor.inhalt;
        cursor = cursor.next;
        return e;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if the code were translated to English.

Comment: Just show the relevant parts of the code that represent your issue

Comment: Maybe someone can show me the simplest code to create a linked list which provides the methods:  insert elements on a specific position, deleted elements on a specific position, shows data of a specific element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you added the first element successfully to the list and now you want to add the second element.

After checking for a valid position you set your current cell to start (`Zelle cur = anfang;`). After that you want to get to the position where you want to insert your object. But since it is your first element there are no following elements. So `cur` will always be `null` after the loop.

Since your list has not a zero-based index you should start your loop with the first index of your list. Try the following loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < p; i++)
{
    if (cur.next == null)
    {
        break;
    }

    cur = cur.next;
}
cursor = cur;
```

Comment: Your answer helps a lot I am now able to use the code. Now it is not clear how to view the first "Zelle" (e.g. I created a for loop which calls the "inhalt" methode, but as in the code stands it begins not with the start cell. There are the methods "inhalt" and  "naechstes" booth are unable to show the first element. The reason is the called method "istGueltigePosition" which do the check "postion >= 1"

Comment: @ChrieJ Please post a new question for your new problem and mark this answer as solution, if it solved the problem you asked in your question.